# Google Appe Engine "Cloud Datastore service" error on deploy

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment, go

Ok, this caused me a **LOT** of pain, so I'm posting this in the hope it helps someone at some point.

You push a Go/Java program to a production App Engine environment, and you get an error, "**Cloud Datastore service**" when you view your app live.

See answer below.

-- shane

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your application doesn't have a "default" version.

Go to the App Engine admin (via https://appengine.google.com) -> "versions" and make sure there is a version set to "default".

This will fix it.

-- shane

Comment: The pleasures of a system that has things that are mandatory at run-time -- but are not mandatory at set-up time.